# How to put block of code below the cursor into curly brackets in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am editing a file with this line of code:

```
operationRunning = false;
```

Now I want to make it conditional, so I put the cursor on the line above and enter the following:

```
if(myCondition == true) {}
operationRunning = false;
```

At this point the cursor sits between the `{` and `}` (because the `}` was added automatically). Is there a shortcut to go from this state to the following:

```
if(myCondition == true) {
  operationRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: Wy you need a shortcut to remove on `} ` and add it one line later?

Comment: use `Enter` and `Alt-DownArrow`

Comment: @rioV8 That's not bad, thanks! But doing it that way I still have to remove one empty line (because pressing enter adds an empty line in between the `{}`) and it also only works for moving a single line of code. What if I have a block of 10 lines?

Comment: you can use `multi-command` to create a sequence of commands that deletes the empty line when you press a modifier combo with `Enter`, you can create a snippet that uses the selected text and wrap an `if () { text }` around it with a key binding insert the snippet

Answer (score 1):

You need an extension that can do multiple steps - [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview) is one that can (I wrote it BTW).

Make this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+s",         // whatever keybinding you want 
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "preCommands": ["cursorHomeSelect"],       // select the current line
    "restrictFind": "selections",              // only work where cursor(s) are
    "postCommands": [
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "snippet": "if(${1:myCondition} == ${2:true}) {\n\t${selectedText}\n}"
        }
      },
      "editor.action.formatSelection"           // fix indentation
    ]
  }
}
```

Start with the cursor at the end of the line you want wrapped.  That text will be wrapped by the conditional and formatted.  The demo shows various levels of indentation being properly formatted.

[image: wrap with conditional statement demo]

Comment: This is great, thank you for taking the time to post and explain it!

Comment: If the answer works for you and you don't get anything better, please consider accepting it.  Thank you.

Comment: It is working fine and it is much appreciated. But let me wait a while because I'm still hoping to get some built-in shortcut trick.